# Web crawling Accuweather

Tags: vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to capture the current weather (88 in image)information from the website

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb1Uo.png)

https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/bengaluru/204108/weather-forecast/204108

I have used the following code

```
Sub Get_Price()
Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
Dim post As HTMLDivElement

With HTTP
.Open "GET", "https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/india-weather", False
.send
HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
MsgBox .responseText
End With

For Each post In HTML.getElementsByClassName("panel-list cityforecast")
With post.getElementsByTagName("large-temp")
 If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
End With
Next post
End Sub
```

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: `large-temp` appear to be classes, not tagNames.

Comment: AccuWeather very probably forbids crawling their site. Get an API access token and use their API. (This will be much easier to do, as well).

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak Is there any possibility to crawl using the script?

Comment: Why would you say "thanks" and then directly ask your original question again? Use the API.

Comment: It's quite unclear which portion of information from that page you wanna scrape. Can you show your desired output. Btw, the link you provided above and the one you used within your script are different.

Comment: @SIM I Have added the image in that I want 88 degree as output

Comment: It's quite unclear what the problem is since you haven't specified what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach to get the information you would like to parse from that page. I used [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) within the script to make it concise but more effective. Give it a shot.

```
Sub GetWeatherInfo()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", "https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/bengaluru/204108/weather-forecast/204108", False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = HTML.querySelectorAll("#feed-tabs .large-temp")(0)
    MsgBox post.innerText
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, V6.0 ''or the version you have
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Btw, before running the script, make sure the url I used is the right one.

Comment: Also can you help me how to get this knowledge?

Comment: Knowledge on what? If about  `.queySelectorAll()` you are talking then I've already provided with the link. However, if it is about webscraping then [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=51) might help. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will check. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you help me to scrap the table from below link/ https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/bengaluru/204108/month/204108?view=table

Comment: Create a new post describing your current requirement and drop a link here. I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149407/scraping-the-table-data-from-accuweather-website

Comment: I think I should kick out my answer from your suggested url as you have found out your desired solution there @Ragu. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SIM In anyways If you require any help let me know. Happy to help you