# Scraping the table data from accuweather website

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, web-crawler

Hi I want to scrap the data from the table. I need all the weather information for all days

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk6qY.jpg)

Please check this link
https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/bengaluru/204108/month/204108?view=table

Source code:

```html
    <tbody>
                                                <tr class="pre">
                                                    <th scope="row">Tue <time>5/1</time></th>
                                                            <td>91&#176;/71&#176;</td>
                                                        <td>0 <span class="small">in</span></td>
                                                        <td>0 <span class="small">in</span></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                            <td>93&#176;/71&#176;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="pre">
                                                    <th scope="row">Wed <time>5/2</time></th>
                                                            <td>91&#176;/75&#176;</td>
                                                        <td>0.03 <span class="small">in</span></td>
                                                        <td>N/A <span class="small">in</span></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                            <td>93&#176;/71&#176;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="today lo calendar-list-cl-tr cl hv" data-href="https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/bengaluru/204108/daily-weather-forecast/204108?day=1">
                                                    <th scope="row"><a href="https://www.accuweather.com/en/in/bengaluru/204108/daily-weather-forecast/204108?day=1">Thu <time>5/3</time></a></th>
                                                    <td>93&#176;/72&#176;</td>
                                                    <td>0.04 <span class="small">in</td>
                                                    <td>0 <span class="small">in</span></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="icon i-17-s"></div>
                                                        <p>A thunderstorm in spots</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                        <td>93&#176;/71&#176;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                                                                           
                                    </tbody>
```

Comment: And now you ask us to do your work? Or what is your question? • This is no free coding service. Please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Also [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) might help.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I am not asking anyone to do my work. I am trying to learn but it takes hell lot of time to understand. Thats why posting it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really directly answer your question but may be the closest you'll get without adding more information to your question and showing that you're making an effort to solve this on your own, by including some code in your question.  Or maybe this ***will*** work better for you:

---

---

Why scrape a site that is willing to practically "hand you" the data, in an easier to handle format, for free?

Accuweather (like many sites) has an API which is free for home use (free up to 50 calls per day) [**Here is a link**](https://developer.accuweather.com/).

However (as a big weather & data geek) I **much** prefer ***DarkSky Weather API***,  which allows up to **1000 calls a day for free** and (depending on *where* you're interested in querying) is the most accurate I've seen. (H The get the data from their own sources combined with everything else they can get their hands on  ([**Here is a link.**](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq))

I have an Access DB that, for over a year now, has bee automatically opening itself every 8 hours (with Windows Task Scheduler) and querying detailed weather 10 days into the future and 3 days into the past, seeking weather trends and ultimately doing a pretty good job of predicting my home heating costs.

In the USA (where I am *not*) they even claim the most accurate forecasts d**own the square-yard, down to the minute**.

> *"It's going to rain this afternoon from 1:17pm until 2:05pm at an average intensity of 0.6mm/hr."*

Plus, DarkSky is the only one with an optional **Emoji Weather Map**.  Not very useful but always good for a chuckle.  lol

[image: img]

Just for fun, here's your area tomorrow... split down the middle there eh?  (They do have *real* data too.)

[image: img]

Anyway it's worth checking out - but as @Peh indicated, you can't expect all the work to be done for you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time @ashleedawg . That makes sense, I will check the website you have suggested